# How to delete a page which is published to non existent target

Tags: web8.5, unpublishing

We are using web 8.5 and detected an issue with one of the page in prod environment. Somehow, it is published to a target that is applicable for another line of business. We aren't sure how its published to that target but maybe while configuring probably it was configured incorrectly and that time someone might have published.

Now that LOB target isn't available to this publication and the editor wants to delete this page. This isn't happening since its published to a non-existent target to this publication.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I Guess you can try to decommission a publication target:

https://docs.sdl.com/792152/129990/sdl-web-8-5--retired-/decommissioning-a-publication-target

But honestly I am not sure if it will work, because it seems you no longer have this target in the system.

Other option is to contact SDL support, and after they inspect your DB, they can provide you with scripts to change publish states to 0 for that target in a supported way.

Third option is to reconfigure this target, do unpublish, and delete it again, but I guess it is too much of an effort.

Comment: Can't use decommission script as the target is in-use for another LOB. Third option we thought but couldn't implement as this is prod env. Hence, only option is to get in touch with SDL. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: oh got it. i mean the easiest way is to just change publish state in cm database for that item, but that Is most definitely not a supported way. so I think you can go with contacting SDL customer support to give you ways how to change It in a supported way.